# Manifest and couple of other static files (fonts) not found after npm run build

Tags: reactjs, fonts, manifest, create-react-app

Manifest and couple of other static files (fonts) not found after npm run build.

The app was created by `create-react-app`.

In the `public/index.html`
`<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">`

Files appear in the build folder and successfully deploys. I can find them using Azure Kudu services.
favicon.ico and other static elements work well. There is an issue only with manifest and two fonts.

For local run :
`"app:start": "react-app-env --env-file=dev.env start"`
`"start": "npm run app:start"`

For the build :
`"app:dev": "react-app-env --env-file=dev.env build"`
`"build": "npm run semantic:build && npm run app:build"`
`"semantic:build": "gulp build --gulpfile ./src/semantic/gulpfile.js"`

> GET https://public.url/manifest.json 404
>
> Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
>
> GET https://public.url/static/media/icons.af7ae505.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>
> GET https://public.url/static/media/icons.fee66e71.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was fixed. 
Added piece of code to the `public/web.config` :

```
<staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".json" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
</staticContent>
```